# How to extract arrays of data (id) from javascript inside SQL statement

Tags: javascript, sql

I have a where clause

```
WHERE sa.id IN({{ testFetchID.value}})
```

Inside the testFetchID.value, the contents are IDs gathered (e.g 1,14,15)

It seems that it's throwing errors saying that the IDs are integers

Here is my testFetchID JS

```
const id = Array.from({{ employeesT.selectedRow.data }}.map((item) => item.id))

return id
```

My error says

> invalid input syntax for integer: "{"1","10"}"

Comment: did you try to `parseInt(item.id)` when you map it ?

Comment: hi Simon, this one is done by using another solution. thank you!